# Problem in Jlist add from one list to another list

Tags: java, swing

I am facing a problem in jlist in java. I have two JLists, I want to add elements from one jlist to another jlist I tried it but it add the element and remove the existing ones present in the list. Here is the code

```
Object[] getListItem = (Object[]) jList2.getSelectedValues();
for(int i=0;i<getListItem.length;i++){
  //jList1.setListData(jList2.getSelectedValues());
  jList1.setListData(getListItem);
}
```

Need Help Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add items to the `ListModel`, not the `JList` itself. The `DefaultListModel` class has methods for adding elements and is similar to the `java.util.Vector` class.

Comment: I am adding it with listModel, but it didn't add any element.

Comment: listModel1.addElement(jList2.getSelectedValues()); where listmodel1 is a DefaultListModel and jlist is a list.

Comment: `JList.getSelectedValues` returns an array of objects, and `DefaultListModel.addElement` adds a single object. You probably want to loop over the result of `getSelectedValues`.